# Unable to start aplication server from Intershop Studio

Tags: eclipse, intershop

After upgrading Intershop project from version 7.10.29.2 to  7.10.38.9-LTS (using Responsive Starter Store 32.2.3) application server can't be started from Intershop Studio any more.
I noticed that the server launch configuration classpath for tools.jar points to the wrong place (${IS_HOME}/engine/jdk/lib/tools.jar instead %JAVA_HOME%/lib/tools.jar) but I was unable to change the classpath permanently  - all changes in classpath configuration are ignored without any warning or error after applying them.

```
    Jun 13, 2022 10:16:21 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner processURLs
    WARNING: Failed to scan [file:/C:/DEV/intershop-ci/sources/projects/webshop/build/server/local/engine/jdk/lib/tools.jar] from classloader hierarchy
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\DEV\intershop-ci\sources\projects\webshop\build\server\local\engine\jdk\lib\tools.jar (The system cannot find the path specified)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:228)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:157)
```

Comment: What Intershop Studio version are you referring to?

Answer (score 2):

It could be related to the selected **Version** field in the **"Server and Developer Home"** configuration. You can find that preference dialog in Window->Preferences->Intershop Studio

Comment: Correct. However, in the current version I have to toggle this setting back and forth once every studio restart.

Comment: Thank you, setting the correct version solved the issue with tools.jar. But still no luck with starting the application server from Studio.  I can start tomcat.bat from the console, but starting the server from Studio or from the console using tomcat_external.bat fails (serializer.jar is missing). I also noticed that starting server in Studio and tomcat_external script boots using org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap and tomcat script using com.intershop.beehive.startup.ServletEngineStartup.

Comment: If your Studio is still trying to use the Bootstrap class to start the AS, clearly there is something wrong. Just shooting in the dark: Did you try a with a new (from scratch) Eclipse workspace? I'm not sure what is all effected by assembling the java command line in Studio.

Comment: @Vankog Happens to me as well, after every restart I have to toggle IS versions so I could start the server

Answer (score 0):

Fixed in newer version. At least in 4.27.2 it works again.
https://repository.cloud.intershop.com/ui/native/studio/com.intershop.studio/